# Ajax calling steps in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

i am working on asp.net using c sharp language. I want to use ajax on drop down. When user selects an item from drop down, the relative information must be shown to user.

Please tell me the steps to use ajax in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so assuming you have a dropdown

```
<select id='drId'>...</select>
```

and an action that will return the info

```
public ActionResult ShowInfo(int v)
{
   // return info about object with key = v
   return Content("hi");
}
```

this script will handle the change client event of the dropdown

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#drId').change(function(){
$.post('<%=Url.Action("ShowInfo")%>',{ v:$(this).val() },function(result){
//do something with result;
alert(result);
});//end post

});//end change
});//end doc ready

//don't forget to include jQuery
</script>
```